# Maximum PHP function nesting level error of NewRelic after turn off cache

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, frontend

When I turn off the cache in Magento I get error from Magento in de Frontend in the Backend I get no error message.

> Fatal error: Aborting! The New Relic imposed maximum PHP function nesting level of '5000' has been reached. This limit is to prevent the PHP execution from catastrophically running out of C-stack frames. If you think this limit is too small, adjust the value of the setting newrelic.special.max_nesting_level in the newrelic.ini file, and restart php. Please file a ticket at https://support.newrelic.com if you need further assistance. in /data/web/public/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 861

Also when I connecting to the API and SoapUI I get the error.

Comment: The error is quite straight forward. It has nothing to do with Magento. It's a New Relic thingie

Comment: hello Yiorgos, It's also a Msgento thing, Why is Magento using 5000 PHP function, the webshop is offline so there ar no customers on the webshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a loop going on somewhere, which means that a method is calling itself or one method is calling another and that method is calling the first one again, over and over again.

You should try to clear cache files in var/cache/ (not only disabling all caches in back end). Now turn of any third party extensions one by one and see if the error goes away so you can detect which extension is causing this.

For other debug help see this great Q&A: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)